# How to Setup and Use Application Insight in a Asp.Net Webforms application

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have an existing legacy webforms application with master pages. I would like to add Application Insight on this site so that I could log requests and page usage. I couldn't find any sample code on this subject while I could find numerous sample code on asp.net core applications. Are there any links you could suggest?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using "Connected Service". It'll configure and install all you need.
Check it out!
[Azure Insights connected service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/azure-app-insights-add-connected-service?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score -1):

> How to Setup and Use Application Insight in a Asp.Net Webforms application

- Create an ASP.Net Web/MVC basic Application
- Select  **Project**  =>  **Add Application Insights Telemetry**  =>  **Application Insights Sdk (local)**  =>  **Next**  =>  **Finish**  =>  **Close**.

[image]

[image]

- ApplicationInsights.config will be created
- Navigate to Azure Portal and create ApplicationInsights Instance. Copy the Instrumentation key from the Overview of the Application Insights

[image]

- In `ApplicationInsights.config`, add the Instrumentation Key which we have copied from the Azure Portal=> ApplicationInsights Instance

[image]

- Run the Application Locally,
  Navigate to the Azure Portal => Application Insights
  You can see the Server Requests,Availability and Failed Requests.
- Navigate to the Live Mtrics option in ApplicationInsights, You can see the Metrics
  [image]
- Here I am using Instrumentation key from Portal, support for instrumentation key ingestion will end on March 31st, 2025

Refer [Transition to connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/migrate-from-instrumentation-keys-to-connection-strings) for using Connection Strings

Please refer [Configure Application Insights for your ASP.NET website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net) for more Information

Comment: Sorry to contact late. I have done exactly as you have described. But I am getting this error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Could you please share your .csproj file package reference file